# Platform for developing all things google?

Tags: java, python, android, platform

I am interested in developing things for google apps and android using python and java. I am new to both and was wondering if a environment set in `windows` or `linux` would be more productive for these tasks?

Comment: That's completely subjective, and should be tagged as such.

Comment: I don't think it's completely subjective.  Sometimes the platform you develop on makes a difference.  This time not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Google has tools for Eclipse only for both [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html) and for [Google Apps](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html).  They haven't made any other tools as far as I know.

Oh yeah, so to answer your question, it doesn't matter that much.  Windows, Unix, or Mac, all the same really (people in our office use all of them).

Answer (score 0):

I'd throw down another vote for Eclipse.  I've been using it on the mac and I find it to be very buggy.  Not sure if that's just the nature of the beast...  My experiences with it on XP have been more stable.  Haven't had time to check it out on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, I believe Google uses Eclipse running on Ubuntu for Android development, so that'd be your best bet if you're completely paranoid about avoiding all potential issues. Of course, this is impossible, and really you should just use whatever you're comfortable in.